# How do you create a char function in C++?

Tags: c++

In C++, how do you make a function to ask the user input, and then store that input? It would ask 3 different chars, and store them

Comment: I can't do it without the function, since it's for a bigger program. 
I have:


char questions()
{
cout <<"Answer this: "<< endl;


cout <<"first question: "<< endl;
cin << answer1;

cout <<"second question "<< endl;
cin << answer2;

cout <<"third question << endl;
cin << answer3;

return answer1, answer2, answer3;
}

Comment: You can only return one thing from a function. You might consider returning a `std::string`, `std::array<char, 3>` or `std::tuple<char, char, char>`. It depends on how you want the result to behave.

Answer (score 3):

That function already exists:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  char a, b, c;
  // read in 3 characters
  std::cin >> a >> b >> c;

  // print them back out
  std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: but to set it up as an actual function I can call in several times?

Comment: @user2328183 can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's called in a game that asks the user to input their response according to instructions. It looks something like this http://pastebin.com/QWf9AqDg
But I can't get it to compile properly

Comment: @user2328183 if you are not sure how to define, declare and implement a function, then I suggest more studying is required. Of course, I could say the same thing about not knowing how to read three characters...

Comment: @NikBougalis I can create the function, read the three characters, store them. I just needed help carrying it out in a function mode...

Answer (score 1):

Hi I believe you can refer to any c++ book and find things like `cin` and `cout`

Generally you need to:

```
char a,b,c;
cin << a << b << c;
```

User should input each char separated by space(s) or `'\n'`.